# access/update global/shared defaultdict from different tornado.RequestHandler instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, defaultdict

Is it safe to access/update a global `defaultdict` from different `RequestHandler` instances? E.g.

```
GlobalMap = defaultdict(list)

class Event(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, unit):
        # This is where the access/modify might happen
        # The list.append() is just an arbitrary example
        GlobalMap[unit].append(datetime.utcnow()) 
        self.write(b'')
```

If not, what’s the proper way to do a lookup/store of keyed data between different `RequestHandler` instances?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine to do. Tornado code typically runs in the main thread; any code that accesses a Python data structure like this.

However, if you're deploying a Tornado application in production you'll want multiple Tornado processes, maybe running on multiple machines, so you'll want to put data in a shared database server to share it among processes.

Comment: I thought "Tornado can scale to tens of thousands of open connections". Does one have to run multiple instances of a tornado server to realize this. If I launch my tornado.py multiple times, wouldn't I need to bind to multiple different socket addresses? And then how would I route incoming traffic to the multiple different internal sockets? All out side of the scope of the original question, but your second paragraph.

Comment: Tornado can handle thousands of connections. Multiple instances can be used to distribute work. The traffic is then load balanced between the instances using gunicron, nginx, or some other load balancer. This is typical of an enterprise level application but if you're using Tornado for personal use, I wouldn't stress too much about multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

In an async/threaded/multiprocess app, accessing global variables are as safe as you make them. As in, it's never really a good idea to have shared states. But for the most part it's fairly safe to access values from a global `dict` especially in an a single threaded async app.

On the other hand, eventually it will become unruly to house all `RequestHandler` classes in a single module. Having a dictionary as a data store will not be able scale out effectively. What `A. Jesse Jiryu Davis` was implying in his answer, is that the data you have in `GlobalMap` should be stored in some sort of database so that it can be shared.  There are a plethora of database solutions which "feel" alot like traditional `dict` objects such as [MongoDB](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and Redis.

## Update

You can also pass in additional parameters when you building your `Application` object. So in your main module you can do something like:

```
GlobalMap = defaultdict(list)

class Event(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, shared_dict):
        self.shared_dict = shared_dict

app = Application([
    #...
    (r"/", Event, dict(shared_dict=GlobalMap))
])
```

Take a look at the [`Application` docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html#the-application-object) and the [`URLSpec` docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.URLSpec). I feel a bit foolish for not recalling this earlier. This will handle accessibility amongst Tornado apps, but not so much with other modules, in which case you would definitely need an external database.

Comment: This application is actually purposely small/simple/single-file. If I make it bigger than one file, I've done something wrong. :) But that aside, to deal with cross module boundaries, could one just put the "global" data as an attribute of the tornado.application instance? And then have the requests just access `self.application._myGlobalMap['foo']` ?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't add a class variable in ``tornado.application``, but I think the easier way would be to simply pass it in during Application creation. See my updated answer. As you can see, I'm fairly new to Tornado too ;P